# how to define models in DJANGO 1.9

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-1.9

I have a model for a project in which I have to use Django and DRF. So I'm making a different file which takes all the objects from my model instances and provide a serializing. But in case of django 1.9 I'm not able to use Model.serializer

```
 from rest_framework import serializers
 from slack.models import WebhookTransaction
 from slack.message import Message

 class WebhookTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
 class Meta:
    model = WebhookTransaction
    fields = '_all_'

 class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
 class Meta:
    model = Message
    fields = '_all_'
```

After running the server it's giving me this error

```
File "/Users/sid/webhook10/tutorial/slack/serializer.py", line 8
class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You have invalid Python syntax. The class definition has to end with a `:`, and the following definitions need to be indented. Going over the Python official tutorial to get a grasp of the basic Python syntax would be worth your time.  [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html]

Answer (score 0):

As [wmorrell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/197681/wmorrell) mentioned in the comment,

> The class definition has to end with a :, and the following definitions need to be indented.

Add semi-colon after your serializers class definations, and indent the code following it, as follows

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from slack.models import WebhookTransaction
from slack.message import Message

class WebhookTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WebhookTransaction
        fields = '_all_'

class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Message
       fields = '_all_'
```